# UML Class Diagram Force.com Project

Tags: force.com, class, diagram

Could you suggest me a way to generate a UML class diagram for a Force.com Project?

Answer (score 3):

I have used the Apex UML free package which can be found [here](http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/03/17/going-native-with-the-apex-uml-tool-and-tooling-api/)

Only basic functionality but was perfect for my needs.

Kudos to [Andy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/286/andrew-fawcett) for the great job !!!

Answer (score 3):

Long before the Force.com Tooling API came out I tried to buid a native tool in Salesforce to render UML class diagrams for Apex classes and SObjects.

[image]

The extraction of the class and object information is solely done in Apex. I really had to use ugly RegExp parsing of classes to get out relationships, fields and object.

This definitly runs into limits or errors if you classes are too complex. So regard this as a proof of concept and...

Feel free to check it out. It can be easily installed (but also forked and improved) on GitHub:
https://github.com/rsoesemann/plantuml4force

Answer (score 1):

Apex is Java like.
A good option is:

1. Found an Open Source Free tool to convert Java code to UML. : ESS Model
   here is the link http://essmodel.sourceforge.net/index.html
2. Copied the .class files from /src folder of my workspace to a new location
3. Renamed all the .cls files to .java files.
   For those who were not born while DOS was the Coolest Operation System around: type ren *.cls *.java in your dos prompt, or http://free-sk.t-com.hr/T800/software/changeExt.htm
4. Ran the tool (ESS Model) and Choose File > Open Folder to the new Folder.

I´m looking forward to know other solutions. Thanks.